# Why do we have to rebuild the app in order to see some change in the device?

Tags: android, apk, titanium-mobile

But for emulator  we don't need to rebuild , it will reflect the changes without rebuilding the app. just go to the back page and come to the changed page, you can see the changes done.
My question is that does the emulator and device use different  apk files? If not then why we need to rebuild the app to deploy in the device?

Comment: Are you sure you mean the emulator?  For the emulator, you must rebuild and redeploy.  Do you mean the layout preview?

Comment: For device, we need to rebuild otherwise we cann't see the changes. for emulator we don't need to rebuild. For database changes we need to rebuild in emulator also but for UI changes and all , we don't need to rebuild for the emulator.

Comment: One of us is very confused :) Do you mean this http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html.  If you have found a way of previewing UI on the emulator without rebuilding, please tell!

Comment: I was telling about the UI changes. Yes, without rebuildin also we can see the changes. just change something in your javascript code , then in emulator open the application and go to the respective page. You can find the changes.

Comment: Eclipse and ADT provide an environment where most of the details of the build process are hidden from you. By default, the build process constantly runs in the background as you make changes to your project.but that's not possible in case of your device and u should rebuild  to see the changes.

Comment: Javascript?  So you're using PhoneGap or something similar?

Comment: Ah, that's it.  You didn't say in your OP.  I thought you had found a way to preview on the emu in native without compiling.

Comment: But i have added a tag for Titanium. I m sorry for the inconvinience:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of FastDev. Developing for Android in combination with the Android emulator Titanium also starts a FastDev Server.

#### What is FastDev?

Well, in short FastDev allows replaces resources for the app on-the-fly. If you change a *.js-File and click on run the file which is used for the emulator is simply replaced by your changed file. This is possible because on emulator titanium is interpreted just in time.

> The Fastdev server enables Titanium developers writing Android apps to
>   rapidly test and see the changes they make in code. Instead of
>   re-deploying the app after changes are made, the app requests whatever
>   it needs under Resources from the Fastdev server. In other words, when
>   Fastdev is running and your app requests app.js (or just about
>   anything under Resources), the latest version of app.js on your dev
>   machine gets served up to the app – there is no need for the full
>   build-and-release process.
>
> Currently Fastdev is only supported for the Android Emulator, but it
>   will also be supported for devices in an upcoming release.

And FastDev - unfortunately - is not available for Devices till today.

Detailed Information are available at http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Fastdev_Reference_for_Android

Comment: This sounds a whole lot like marketing material.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Why? This is official information you can also find when clicking the link. If it sounds like marketing i should think about my job and maybe change...

Comment: Why does it sound like marketing? Because that's all it is. Instead of code samples, it is just marketing-speak. I recommend updating the answer to include some code-related info - not just a sale pitch.

Comment: What code would you like to see? I explained how it works. It works in the background. There are no code samples... of course you can control the server with some commands, but simply developing with titanium studio on android emulator doesn't require this. I don't get your problem.